How to locate a device by container ID?
After bringing my machine up from a power failure, my Windows 11 machine pinged at me every few seconds, playing the "device was disconnected" sound.  Pulling open the Device Manager verified something fishy was going on in the hardware, as it refreshed with every chime.
Because I couldn't validate the exact cause from Device Manager (due to a lack of detectable change every refresh), I opened Event Viewer and noticed that the logs were spammed with the following:

Metadata staging failed, result=0x80070490 for container '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-008BAB50C82E}'

After probing through Device Manager's "Devices by Container" view, checking a node out of each top-level device, I narrowed it down to my Index headset; resetting its connection quieted the constant chiming and fixed its issue.
The question I have here is, should something like this happen again in the future, how can I enumerate the various containers by their IDs to locate the problem device?  All I could find through an (admittedly cursory) search on Google was how to find devices by the device IDs, which isn't helpful in this case.

Your actions, using Device Manager and viewing the devices by Container, are exactly what you should have done.

There is no way to say, "here are all of the devices, and here are all of their container IDs"?

I am seeing the same errors ("Metadata Staging Failed") and was searching for a way to find the device information by container ID. You can use pnputil /enum-devices /properties to get properties of all the connected devices and redirect it's output to a file (pnputil /enum-devices /properties > C:\path\file.txt) and search inside the file using Notepad or something with the container ID to find it below the appropriate device.
